# apache security is this possible

Tags: ajax, apache

I have a third party product on my machine that has it's own built in webserver.

I have apache installed on the same machine and have my own custom webpage, that using AJAX would like to get some data from the third party website.

I am coming across Cross domain security issues, since both sites are on the same machine is it possible to alter anything in apache that would allow my site to talk to the other site via Ajax?

This is a subject I know very little about!!!!

thanks

Comment: Proxying as the answers so far suggest would be one way to handle this – CORS would be another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you configure apache in a way that both your application and the third party application are served from within the same domain, they can talk to each other. You could use mod_proxy to serve data from the third party application and a Alias directive to serve your own application.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com

Alias /myapp "C:\program files\homeseer\html" 
ProxyPass /thirdpartyapp http://192.168.0.34:81/thirdpartyapp
ProxyPassReverse /thirdpartyapp http://192.168.0.34:81/thirdpartyapp
</VirtualHost>
```

This would make your app available at www.example.com/myapp and the third party app at www.example.com/thirdpartyapp.

Comment: I am, so bad at this!!! the third party site currently responds on 192.168.0.34:81 My site is //localhost/hsphptest/index.php  if I amend your example do I then amend mod_proxy??

Comment: I have modified the example. Where is your app located on your machine? In which folder?

Comment: Thanks I see that does am I right in thinking I don't have to do anything with mod_proxy now??  Thanks again!

Comment: how does www.example.com get resolved I don't have any dns enteries for it?

Comment: Well you will have to replace "www.example.com" with the dns name of the machine you are running apache on.

Answer (score 0):

[mod proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) would allow your Apache server to talk to the other server and return data through the same domain.